# Pod install GPUImage does not work

Tags: swift, gpuimage

I am working on a Swift project with *cocoapods*. Here is Podfile:

```
pod 'GPUImage', '~> 0.1.4'
```

1. After i run `pod install`, i try got the error about import file:

   import GPUImage
   [image]

I uninstalled GPUImage from podfile, then try the second solution, i got different error.

2. This [link](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage#adding-this-as-a-framework-module-to-your-mac-or-ios-project) is the project instruction on github. My steps are:

   - Copy&Paste GPUImage.xcodeproj into project root directory, and added it into my project.
   - Go to "**Build settings**" -> "**Build Phases**" -> "**Target Dependencies**", added **PUImageFramework**, in **Link Binary With Libraries** section, added **GPUImage.framework**.

But i got an error:

```
error: unable to read module map contents from 'Source/iOS/Framework/module.modulemap': Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “module.modulemap” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x7f872cfb0b80 {NSFilePath=/Users/william/A/muguang-ios/Source/iOS/Framework/module.modulemap, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f87413f4dd0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}
```

Any help, thx!

**EDIT:**

The error right now is:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/GPUImage.framework/GPUImage
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9CF1D10C-1D78-40CB-955F-19110B3C3EA8/testGDU.app/testGDU
  Reason: image not found
```

**EDIT**:
For solution without using pods, here is solution:

> You then need to add a new Copy Files build phase, set the Destination
>   to Frameworks, and add the GPUImage.framework build product to that.
>   This will allow the framework to be bundled with your application
>   (otherwise, you'll see cryptic "dyld: Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/GPUImage.framework/GPUImage" errors on execution).

But question 1 with cocoapods still not work.

Comment: getting the same error for SnapKit with cocoapods. Did you find a solution for pods?

Comment: I gave up pods install, add it manually.

Comment: I sorted mine with cocoapods `0.36.4` and also mine had a issue where one file didn't have class definition and this was the actual cause of the error not even pods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's my bad, i got the solution:

> You then need to add a new Copy Files build phase, set the Destination
>   to Frameworks, and add the GPUImage.framework build product to that.
>   This will allow the framework to be bundled with your application
>   (otherwise, you'll see cryptic "dyld: Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/GPUImage.framework/GPUImage" errors on execution).

Comment: For Pals still looking in 2021, please check the destination in Copy Files of Build phases, it should be framework as mentioned above( My destination was set to resources)

Comment: can you pls add more details how to do that @Vivek

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with the following library versions:

- Xcode 6.3
- Cocoapods 0.37.2

Finally I solved this issue by the following steps:

**First step:**

1. Open Xcode
2. Click Window (Menu Bar)
3. Click Projects
4. Remove all projects (e.g. use backspace)
5. Close Xcode

**Second Step:**

1. Open a terminal app
2. `cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
3. `rm -rf Build/*`  *see below if you have a customized build location*
4. `rm -rf ModuleCache/*`
5. Close a terminal app

**Third Step:**

1. Open Xcode
2. Product > Clean
3. Product > Run

> **If you have defined a custom build location:**
>
> 1. Go with Finder or the Terminal to the location of the build files. The location for these files is defined in Xcode. To check where these files are:
>
>    - Open Xcode
>    - Go to `Settings -> Locations -> Derived Data`
> 2. Go to that location and delete the `Build` folder

Then everything work well.

Hope this can help somebody in the future.

Comment: This did it for me, including deleting all the files of the previously build projects: Go with Finder or the Terminal to the location of these files → `Open Xcode -> Settings -> Locations -> Derived Data` and delete everything

Comment: I got clear failed by your answer step, my errors come after convert swift2 to swift3.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, just change Develop account in Signing & Capabilities then build app again. It works