# Can't find Pods.modulemap - looking in wrong directory

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I'm trying to get CocoaPods working in a Swift project but this is my first time.

My Podfile is

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.2'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2.0'
```

I run `pod install` but building it gives me this error:

```
Error: unable to read module map contents from 'Target Support 
Files/Pods/Pods.modulemap': Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260
 "The file “Pods.modulemap” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." 
UserInfo=0x7fac488d5af0 {NSFilePath=/Users/jt/tmp-ios/my-template/Pods/Target 
Support Files/Pods/Pods.modulemap, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fac457f0e90 "The operation 
couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}
```

The weird is that this is that /Users/jt/tmp-ios/ is not even the directory I am in.

```
Tue Jun 09$ pwd
/Users/jt/repos/EmbersSwift
Tue Jun 09$
```

I did have something in that directory before by what it is referencing that is not clear. How would I fix this? I suspect it is something in Pods.debug.xconfig but was hoping somebody had dealt with this before.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution for this? I have the feeling this errors keeps coming up and disappearing from time to time. I'm using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON as well, but it searches the modulemap in the wrong folder.... - I'm wondering if it has to do that the project uses frameworks?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was:

> **First step:**
>   *(this step may no longer be needed in Xcode 9.x and newer)*
>
> 1. Open Xcode
> 2. Click Window (Menu Bar)
> 3. Click Projects
> 4. Remove all projects (e.g. use backspace)
> 5. Close Xcode
>
> **Second Step:**
>
> 1. Open a terminal app
> 2. `cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
> 3. `rm -rf Build/*`  *see below if you have a customized build location*
> 4. `rm -rf ModuleCache/*`
> 5. Close a terminal app
>
> **Third Step:**
>
> 1. Open Xcode
> 2. Product > Clean
> 3. Product > Run
>
> Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30752152/756976

**If you have defined a custom build location:**

1. Go with Finder or the Terminal to the location of the build files. The location for these files is defined in Xcode. To check where these files are:

   - Open Xcode
   - Go to `Settings -> Locations -> Derived Data`
2. Go to that location and delete the `Build` folder

---

**Edit: June 9, 2016**

It is also possible that this resolves your problem:

By default the clean of Xcode, does not delete everything, by going to `Product`, pressing the `ALT`-key, the `Clean`-button will change to `Clean Build Folder...`.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: @AllenLin I am not sure. I would like to say it is (or was) a compatibility bug between Xcode, Cocoapods, Modules. Since it never occurred again later and I am also not able to reproduce this problem I assume that they resolved this issue, or at least did some improvements.

Comment: I'm using XCode 8.1. In its Window menu, I don't see `Projects` (First step - 3.). Where can I find it?

Comment: @quanguyen did you find it ?

Comment: Use`pod deintegrate` + `pod setup` to fix totally

Comment: pod reintegrate and pod setup had no effect for me.

Comment: @skofgar, when I click on window I see Minimize, Zoom, Developer Documentation, Welcome to Xcode, Devices and Simulators, Organizer, Show Touch Bar, Bring all to Front, Pods empty tab.  I don't see projects.

Comment: Hello @ScottyBlades, it looks like newer versions of Xcode (maybe 9.x) do not contain that menu anymore...  I assume omitting step 1 didn't help?

Comment: @ScottyBlades you might need to create a new question or send me some details. I will take a look and see if I have any input that might help.

Answer (score 9):

In my case I had made a few changes to my PodFile, got a similar error and just re-ran 'install':

```
% pod install
```

And I was back in business.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by removing the pods from the pod file, pod install, add them again, then pod install again.

looks like a pod was incorrectly installed.

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem happened to me with **core data** when reseting changes that involved core new version from the source control (Git). it threw:

> /Path/To/Model/Model.xcdatamodel: Failed to read data model Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “contents” couldn’t be
>   opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Path/To/Model/Model.xcdatamodel/contents, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fb632e558d0
>   {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

I was unable to build the project because of that error I've tried the above solution but it didn't work.

What worked for me was:

1. Open the RootModel.xcdatamodel (Left click on the model and Show in Finder).
2. Manually erase the Model.xcdatamodel that triggets the issue.
3. Clean project (cmd+shift+k) and Run.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way though is going to Xcode's Preferences

```
Preferences->Locations->Derived Data
```

Just deleting Derived Data folder does the trick. Just Clean and Build the project again after, should not throw any errors.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to go to the project directory, where the pod file is. 
and:

```
rm -f Podfile.lock
rm -rf Pods/
```

That actually removed all the culprits and I was able to build and run the project again.

( I also did the previously mentioned steps, removed build folder and module caches, but that didn't help)