# Q: Dependency Analysis Error after swift2 convert to swift3

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, swift3, alamofire

Before I ask the question I have searched many relate questions:

[can't find Pods.modulemap - looking in wrong directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745675/cant-find-pods-modulemap-looking-in-wrong-directory) 
I do step by this link and I can not get the result.
and before this I update my `cocoapods`and other try.
now when I clean my project, it get clean failed.

keep this status all the time: and be carefully the `schedule bar`'s status is all the time `cleaning prject_name:Finishing...`

[image: errors too much]

and there is so many red errors, how can I resolve this? convert to `swift3` comes so many errors, and they are almost like this:

```
error: unable to read module map contents from 'Target Support Files/Result/Result.modulemap': Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “Result.modulemap” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/youpude/Desktop/companyProject/欢喜收钱/3-code/iOS/happyCollection/Pods/Target Support Files/Result/Result.modulemap, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe5366beeb0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later, I learned that, `IQKeyboardManager` in `swift3` has changed its name to `IQKeyboardManagerSwift` in its version `4.0.7`:

the solution is in the `podfile`, add :

```
pod 'IQKeyboardManager', '~>  4.0.6'
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '~> 4.0.7'
```

and install pods, will solve the issue.