# How to fix cocoapod .modulemap file not found

Tags: cocoapods, xcode10.2

When I try to build my project, I get a compile time error saying that a "Module map file" for my pod cannot be found and that I am missing a "SwiftShimes" module.

This is weird because all my modulemap files are where they should be when I install my pods.

I am using Xcode 10.2 and Cocoapods 1.6.1.

I have tried the following ->

- deintegrating cocoapods from my project
- cleaning the project
- deleted ModuleCache and DerivedData
- restarting my computer

This is the type of error I am getting ->

```
Module map file '/Users/kaunamohammed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OutNow-gxdxvzwmnijmrlajtbtyclkhrgqs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/CodableFirebase/CodableFirebase.modulemap' not found
```

I expect my project to build properly but this is not the case and I am not sure what else to do.

This is what my Podfile looks like

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

workspace 'OutNow'

target 'OutNow' do
  use_modular_headers!
  #Pods for OutNow
  pod 'Instabug'
  pod 'SwiftMessages'
  pod 'CodableFirebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
  pod 'MarqueeLabel/Swift'
  pod 'RxSwift', '4.4.2'
  pod 'RxCocoa', '4.4.2'
  pod 'Kingfisher', '5.3.1'
  pod 'InstantSearchClient', '6.0'
  pod 'CoordinatorLibrary', '1.0.5'
  pod 'UIScrollView-InfiniteScroll', '1.1.0'

  target 'OutNowTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: The latest version of CocoaPods is 1.6.something and there's a 1.7 beta floating around. I'd update your CocoaPods to the latest release version (1.6.something) and try `pod install` again. Also, you might want to post your `Podfile`, as you could be installing the wrong version of Alamofire. Lastly, are you opening the workspace, not the project?

Comment: I have now updated to the latest stable version of cocoapods and done pod install but the problem still persists

Comment: Did you take a peek at this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30836224/4475605

Comment: Yes I did. The problem still persists unfortunately

Comment: try adding `use_frameworks!` just below the `platform <blah blah>` line, as is done in the installation instructions for [CodableFirebase](https://github.com/alickbass/CodableFirebase).

Comment: It now says "FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found" and "Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase' "

Comment: Ugh! Try commenting out the modular header line.

Comment: Still not working. I commented out both #use_modular_headers! and #use_frameworks! but now nothing is being loaded which makes sense. Also tried using them individually, but I get some form of error either way

Comment: For some strange reason everything seems to work now. Thanks for the help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191815/discussion-between-adrian-and-kauna-mohammed).

Comment: yeah, I opened the wrong file and I have worked on react-native for 8 years, lol

Answer (score 231):

In case it helps anyone else, I was able to solve this issue a different way. I was accidentally opening up my `.xcproject` instead of my `.xcworkspace`. When I opened the correct file, the error went away.

Comment: Once of reason need to check:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69711515/454666

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution for me. Also, I had to restart Xcode.

Comment: Yes, This helped me.

Answer (score 64):

I fixed this problem myself. I can tell you what I did. Not sure which steps did it exactly, but below are all steps:

1. Copy the contents of your Podfile somewhere safe
2. Run: `pod cache clean --all`
3. Remove "Podfile"-file from the dir.
4. Xcode: **Product** > **Clean Build Folder**
5. Run: `pod init`. A new "Podfile"-file is added to the dir
6. Start adding parts of your original Podfile to this file
7. Run: `pod install`
8. Try to build your project again

In my case, I think the row `use_frameworks!` in the "Podfile" did the trick.

Hope this help you guys out!

Comment: I just did steps 2, 4 & 7 and it worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot saved my day. I think @lewis has a point, 2, 4 & 7 also seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 35):

I had this issue only when I wanted to make an **archive**. On the other hand, debug worked fine. After a while I noticed that min iOS version was different between my Target, Project and Podfile min iOS version. After syncing them all to same value (iOS 11) *Xcode offered me Validate Project Settings - Update to recommended settings* option which I accepted and I was able to archive my project.

Comment: Thanks. After updating the iOS version in the pod file, target, and project to the same value. It worked fine.

Comment: I had the same issue with the newest Stripe pod in React native - I have bumped up the target in the Podfile, installed all the pods, the app worked fine in debug but I couldn't archive it because I didn't update min iOS version in the Project settings. Works fine now!

Comment: I spent 2 days on this. I had indeed iOS 11 in my Podfile but iOS 10 in my project and target.
Thank you so much @josip-b 

Comment: Thanks for this answer! 
I had the same issue and just setting the version to the same (11) everywhere fixed it. 
So it was caused by increasing the required version only in the Podfile but not elsewhere!

Comment: I ensured deployment target is same across target, project and pod file. But still getting error. Can you please help me in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 34):

I spent a whole day trying to figure out how to solve this issue. I was facing issue in my project on M1 machine.

I enabled "Open using Rosetta" option in Xcode and worked for me.

Here is how you do that:
Open Finder --> Applications --> Right click "Xcode" --> Get Info --> check "Open using Rosetta"

Comment: Is this still the only solution in mid-2022, Xcode should work with native architecture, isn't it? Sad to run it in Rosseta, feels like I cannot take the full advantage of my machine.

Comment: omg i was tryin to work it for months. thanks it worked

Comment: Running Xcode in Rosseta, I'm able to compile and run the app. But it occasionally crash the system (reboot). It seems not very stable.

Comment: I had to select a different scheme and build config. I was then able to build for Rosetta. The 'Build for Rosetta' popup shows up within xcode when we start the build process

Answer (score 12):

Just check that you opened the **.xcworkspace** file and not the .xcproject file with Xcode.

Comment: This has already been mentioned in other answers, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59696931/2227743).

Answer (score 6):

I solve this issue by removing `OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS` custom flag in `Swift Compiler - Custom Flags`

`OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS = "$(inherited) -D COCOAPODS -Xcc -fmodule-map-file=\"${PODS_ROOT}/modulePath/moduleName.modulemap\"";`

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried it but not worked

Answer (score 4):

If anyone still has this issue with Xcode 14.3, I resolved it with the following:

In Xcode choose Product -> Destination -> Destination Architectures -> Show Rosetta Destination

Then clean your build folder and try again, for me it worked fine

Comment: Worked! how is this solving the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I faced this same issue but with Fastlane using gym `build_app`.

I ensured that min iOS version was synched between my Target, Project, and Podfile as mentioned by Josip B. This allowed me to archive my app using XCode but it still failed using Fastlane.

After lots of searching, it was able to resolve my issue by ensuring the `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` version for each of my installed Pods inherited the version from my `Podfile` using this Podfile post-install script:

```rb
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
      end
    end
  end
```

Reference this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63489366/10211406

Answer (score 2):

In case you are building on command line with `xcodebuild`, make sure you are using

```
xcodebuild -workspace ...
```

instead of just `xcodebuild` or

```
xcodebuild -project ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this issue after switching branches in git, because the **build configuration** for the **scheme** I had selected was one that did not exist on the current branch. Switching the **build configuration** for the `Run` scheme cleared the issues immediately.

```
Click on your target in the top bar
Edit Scheme
Choose an appropriate build config.
```

I've had this issue in the past and it was resolved by following the steps in [Ton Snoei's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2497144/ton-snoei) answer (specifically, steps 2, 4, and 7), but recently experienced it again and no manipulation of the podfile or removal/addition of pods was solving it until I changed the build config.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. If you are using a Mac on M1/M2, try to open Xcode through Rosetta.

Right click on Xcode in applications folder -> Get Info -> turn on "Open with Rosetta" check box.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too, I'm not very familiar with XCode, but I opened the .xcodeworkspace file and then clicked build, which was successful!

Answer (score 0):

It´ s a bit of a hack but try adding this in your podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  if (target.name&.eql?('FBReactNativeSpec'))
    target.build_phases.each do |build_phase|
      if (build_phase.respond_to?(:name) && build_phase.name.eql?('[CP-User] Generate Specs'))
        target.build_phases.move(build_phase, 0)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you add it to your bridge file, and Try to add this at the end of your podfile:

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
            config.build_settings['BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION'] = 'YES'
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Tried this on Mac m1, gives a different error
---
Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCoreInternal.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FirebaseCoreInternal.swiftinterface:5:19: error: underlying Objective-C module 'FirebaseCoreInternal' not found
@_exported import FirebaseCoreInternal
                  ^
---

Answer (score 0):

The same error comes with Xcode 14 when archiving a build if you have the scheme name with spaces (Example: AppName Dev). Remove spaces and the build will archive successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

1. Terminal: pod cache clean --all
2. Xcode: Product > Clean Build Folder
3. Terminal: pod install

Try to build your project again

Answer (score -2):

What helped for me in similar situation is to use different Node version (to match RN recommendation). Downgraded it from 16 to 12 (RN 63.x)