# YogaKit.modulemap not found after running the IOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

I have problems running my IOS Simulator within XCode, everytime I try to run the simulator, I get an error message saying:

`"fatal error: module map file '/Users/maurice/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/feedIt-etmfdpwrwadziocunpypqhkwucsd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap' not found"`

Expected behavior:
XCode runs the simulator.

Actual Behavior:
The Build fails and I get the described error message.

I already tried to update Pods and delete the Derived Data, but apparently that didn't work.

How can I fix this issue?

I'm running on MacOS 10.15.5 and XCode 11.6

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Please see "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)" along with "[mre]".

Comment: Removing Podfile.lock and then "pod install" fixed it for me

Answer (score 111):

According to the comments in this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28503), the problem could be that you opened up `.xcodeproj` instead of `.xcworkspace`. Some of the other suggested fixes include:

1. Make sure your cocoapods build target is the same version as your projects build target. [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28503#issuecomment-643744117)
2. Try rebooting your machine. [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28503#issuecomment-622015019)
3. Examine your podfile to make sure your build scheme is included in it. [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28503#issuecomment-669987293)

I was experiencing a similar issue when trying to build the project from the command line and the root issue was that I was using the `.xcodeproj` instead of `.xcworkspace`. From what I could tell this error could be caused by multiple different factors.

Comment: I had an extra comma left in my code located in my podfile, removing it fixed the problem

Answer (score 26):

If you are using M1 chip

1. Add `arm64` in **Excluded Architecture**
   [image]
2. Add following lines in **podfile**
   [image]
3. Remove node_modules from root, Podfile.lock and Pods from ios folder
4. Run in root terminal `yarn install && cd ios && pod install && pod update`
5. Clean your project and open again
6. Wait for indexing the project
7. Run project

Comment: Please add more step after two is ->  remove all paths except $(inherited). From Build Settings -> Library Search paths.

Comment: Does not work: following build commands failed: SwiftEmitModule normal x86_64 Emitting\ module\ for\ ...

Answer (score 16):

Add this to your Podfile if you are using a M1 chip Mac

```
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
    end
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Comment: Tried running the project in my simulator for about 2 years and finally this answer saved me.

Comment: Happy to be of help! Took a long time to find this too

Comment: Thanks this was the only answer worked for me

Answer (score 14):

Described solution will work 100% on Apple silicon and while running Xcode without rosetta.

Please try necessary steps only but if still not work than Please try everything including necessary and unnecessary steps.

1 - Not important(Package.json)

```
"dependencies": {
 "react": "17.0.1",
 "react-native": "0.64.2"
}
```

---

2 - necessary

```
  use_flipper!()
  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
        installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config| config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] =  "arm64"
        end
  end
```

OR

```
  use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings["ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH"] = "NO"
          end
      end
  end
```

---

3 - Add `arm64` under Architectures->Excluded Architectures

---

4 - Add a *swift file* under your project, can be empty, can be BridgingFile.swift(nothing special in it), this will trigger a bridging header. **Wallah, here you go.**

[image]

Comment: Xcode runs without Rosetta sure, but your app binary still compiled for x86_64 and still run under Rosetta, you can verify this in the Activity Monitor. Rosetta is not going to ship work forever, so we need a proper solution anyway

Answer (score 11):

The issue I was facing when I received this error was, I had opened the wrong file in Xcode. Instead of opening the '*.xcworkspace' file, I opened the '*.xcodeproj' file.

The solution to this issue is to open the '*.xcworkspace' file in Xcode instead of the '*.xcodeproj' file.

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers.

Answer (score 2):

I have got an **M1 mac setup**. The above methodologies were not working for me.
However, this worked: Run XCode Rosetta

> Finder -> Xcode in applications folder -> Get Info -> set Open with
> Rosetta to true

Xcode is now under Rosetta.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem with adding to Debug Any iOS Simulator SDK with value arm64 to excluded architecture in Pods project (apple MacBook
Pro m1)

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a comment. See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, this is solved by changing
**build active architecture only > release > yes** in build settings

Answer (score 1):

make sure to your deployment target should be same in podfile, project and target.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was not setting the VALID_ARCHS = "arm64 arm64e armv7 armv7s x86_64"; like this in xyzApp/ios/xyzApp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try running the project on on terminal with this command:
npx react-native run-ios
and the run it on Xcode again

Comment: this command is working run in simulator. but when try to run from Xcode to my iPhone, getting same error. So, problem is only when running in mobile. What Can I do now?

Comment: unfortunately no.

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- run `brew uninstall watchman`
- run `brew install watchman` or `arch arm64 brew install watchman` if you are on an M1
- closed the current terminal (console) session
- open it again and go to the project directory
- `cd ios && rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock && pod install --repo-update`
- run `watchman watch-del-all`
- if you have the iOS simulator opened, closed it
- run `yarn react-native run-los`

Answer (score -1):

Once of reason can export this error is setting on `User-Defined`. Recently, I pull a project to continue dev. I can't build it on simulator. It's always so this error.

> Module map not found

for all lib. Its take me a lot of times to fix this. I check of all config & found problem is previous dev set `VALID_ARCHS` are only: `arm64e armv7s arm64`

I changed it to both ios device & simulator: `arm64 arm64e armv7 armv7s x86_64` or simple delete `VALID_ARCHS` from `User-Defined`.

Now it can work. Hope this help :-)

Answer (score -2):

I was seeing this error with a different package and in a React Native setting, and could not find anything on how to fix it. After a lot of trial and error I found a solution:

1. Open the `ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj` in XCode
2. That showed a number of warnings in the Pods project, which XCode suggested it could fix
3. Ask XCode to fix the warnings

After this I was able to build the project again, both through XCode and using the React Native tooling.