# I could archive a iOS app in my react-native project

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

When i am trying upload the app to the testflight and in this process when i am archiving the build. The build was getting failed. Below i will attach image of errors :

[image]

Comment: @Mark when i am trying to archive

Comment: Does this answer your question? [YogaKit.modulemap not found after running the IOS Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63261150/yogakit-modulemap-not-found-after-running-the-ios-simulator)

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me if i open .xcworkspace rather than .xcodeproj.

Comment: With REACT-NATIVE you have to use always .xcworkspace because it keeps all the reference to CocoaPods and your targets.