# FirebaseCoreInternal.modulemap not found, trying to build an ios scheme by xcodebuild

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, xcode14, xcode-tools

i'm trying to build my ios app via xcodebuild.
I want to build an specific scheme instead of the whole project (too heavy), so i run this command:

```bash
xcodebuild build -scheme "Glik" -sdk iphoneos -destination generic/platform=iOS
```

but it always fails, with this fatal error:

`fatal error: module map file '/Users/pablo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Glik-bxbwmzcivjasbkbiqxqkmjmbxeli/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseCoreInternal/FirebaseCoreInternal.modulemap' not found`

Maybe is worth mention that i can build the workspace, but it takes too long to use it in a Github Action (it stops at 20ish minutes)

I expect to perform the build of the scheme, to use it on a Github Actions CI/CD to make easier all the build and deploy process of the app.
I have tried deleting the cache data, the derived data and all that kind of stuff.
Also i tried trying yo build the app in rosetta, but it did not work either.
I have found similar issues like this [YogaKit.modulemap not found after running the IOS Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63261150/yogakit-modulemap-not-found-after-running-the-ios-simulator), bur they don't have the solution i need.

Thanks in advance!

this is my Podfile:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

target 'Glik' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    # Upcoming versions of React Native may rely on get_default_flags(), but
    # we make it explicit here to aid in the React Native upgrade process.
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'GlikTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
      # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end

  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'

  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera"
  pod 'Permission-LocationAlways', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationAlways"
  pod 'Permission-LocationAccuracy', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationAccuracy"
  pod 'Permission-LocationWhenInUse', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationWhenInUse"
  pod 'Permission-BluetoothPeripheral', :path => "#{permissions_path}/BluetoothPeripheral"
  
end
```