# How to fix module map file CocoaLumberjack.modulemap not found

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoalumberjack

Mac m1 xcode 13 above react-native (if that matters).

Got Error:
:0: error: module map file '[path to CocoaLumberjack]/CocoaLumberjack.modulemap' not found

tried:

- pod cache clean --all
- Clean project
- pod install --> Build

Still got the error - any advice?
Saw [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55675694/how-to-fix-cocoapod-modulemap-file-not-found) that is similar but its not CocoaLumberjack specific - none of the answers there helped me