# Multiple modulemap not found errors in react-native ios execution

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, package.json

I run my react-native ios project using these commands:

```
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf node_modules/ && yarn cache clean && yarn install
pod install --repo-update
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 14"
```

Which gives me this error when running ios

```
<unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/asumobileapp-btkzbdfsdnhmcqayttujwctmcifk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCoreInternal/FirebaseCoreInternal.modulemap' not found
    <unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/asumobileapp-btkzbdfsdnhmcqayttujwctmcifk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap' not found
    <unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/asumobileapp-btkzbdfsdnhmcqayttujwctmcifk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-ios/Lottie.modulemap' not found
    <unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/asumobileapp-btkzbdfsdnhmcqayttujwctmcifk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-react-native/lottie_react_native.modulemap' not found
    <unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/asumobileapp-btkzbdfsdnhmcqayttujwctmcifk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-geolocation-service/react_native_geolocation_service.modulemap' not found
    <unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/asumobileapp-btkzbdfsdnhmcqayttujwctmcifk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-in-app-review/react_native_in_app_review.modulemap' not found
```

My package.json file and Podfile are in this [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/u/shehlaaltafk/1/keHPj2Ve). I've tried every other solution on StackOverflow but I cannot seem to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

- the module map files for some of your dependencies are missing. This usually happens when the dependencies are not properly linked or installed.
- How to fix cocoapod .modulemap file not found : [How to fix cocoapod .modulemap file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55675694/how-to-fix-cocoapod-modulemap-file-not-found)
- module map file '/Users/hosein/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sporty-ficshtjjzxcsgkaohfxowaxpyivr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap' not found : https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/670006
- xcode 11.4 build fatal error: module map file xxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap' not found #28503 : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28503