# The following build commands failed: CompileC BUILD FAILED

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, rubygems

It was working, I just restarted my computer (iMAC M1) and "pouf"!

(I had no problem before, my App works.)

Here I give you what I get:

```
CompileC /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dzwwympbnncmhxbpmvkfeqqwcchk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.o /Users/[USER]/Desktop/react-native-mobile/ios/ReactNativeMobile/AppDelegate.mm normal arm64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'ReactNativeMobile' from project 'ReactNativeMobile')
    cd /Users/[USER]/Desktop/react-native-mobile/ios
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c++ -ivfsstatcache /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDKStatCaches.noindex/iphonesimulator17.4-21E210-aa93b11c43e2d16681ac3fa171344f4f.sdkstatcache -fmessage-length\=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit\=0 -fno-color-diagnostics -fmodules-prune-interval\=86400 -fmodules-prune-after\=345600 -fbuild-session-file\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror\=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror\=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror\=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Werror\=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -Wno-c++11-extensions -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wmove -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wrange-loop-analysis -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -index-store-path /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dzwwympbnncmhxbpmvkfeqqwcchk/Index.noindex/DataStore @/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dzwwympbnncmhxbpmvkfeqqwcchk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build/Objects-normal/arm64/af3fcb34312c57c0f52879cdce924b91-common-args.resp -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dzwwympbnncmhxbpmvkfeqqwcchk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dzwwympbnncmhxbpmvkfeqqwcchk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.dia -c /Users/[USER]/Desktop/react-native-mobile/ios/ReactNativeMobile/AppDelegate.mm -o /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dzwwympbnncmhxbpmvkfeqqwcchk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.o -index-unit-output-path /ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.o
In file included from /Users/[USER]/Desktop/react-native-mobile/ios/ReactNativeMobile/AppDelegate.mm:1:
/Users/[USER]/Desktop/react-native-mobile/ios/ReactNativeMobile/AppDelegate.h:1:9: fatal error: 'RCTAppDelegate.h' file not found
#import <RCTAppDelegate.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

CompileStoryboard /Users/[USER]/Desktop/react-native-mobile/ios/ReactNativeMobile/LaunchScreen.storyboard (in target 'ReactNativeMobile' from project 'ReactNativeMobile')
    cd /Users/[USER]/Desktop/react-native-mobile/ios
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --module ReactNativeMobile --output-partial-info-plist /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dzwwympbnncmhxbpmvkfeqqwcchk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build/LaunchScreen-SBPartialInfo.plist --auto-activate-custom-fonts --target-device iphone --minimum-deployment-target 13.4 --output-format human-readable-text --compilation-directory /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dzwwympbnncmhxbpmvkfeqqwcchk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build /Users/[USER]/Desktop/react-native-mobile/ios/ReactNativeMobile/LaunchScreen.storyboard

CompileAssetCatalog /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dzwwympbnncmhxbpmvkfeqqwcchk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.app /Users/[USER]/Desktop/react-native-mobile/ios/ReactNativeMobile/Images.xcassets (in target 'ReactNativeMobile' from project 'ReactNativeMobile')
    cd /Users/[USER]/Desktop/react-native-mobile/ios
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool --output-format human-readable-text --notices --warnings --export-dependency-info /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dzwwympbnncmhxbpmvkfeqqwcchk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build/assetcatalog_dependencies --output-partial-info-plist /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dzwwympbnncmhxbpmvkfeqqwcchk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist --app-icon AppIcon --compress-pngs --enable-on-demand-resources YES --filter-for-thinning-device-configuration iPhone16,2 --filter-for-device-os-version 17.2 --development-region en --target-device iphone --minimum-deployment-target 13.4 --platform iphonesimulator --compile /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dzwwympbnncmhxbpmvkfeqqwcchk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.app /Users/[USER]/Desktop/react-native-mobile/ios/ReactNativeMobile/Images.xcassets


--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:10488651-8275-4D12-A891-0BC37CE8F11F, OS:17.2, name:iPhone 15 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:10488651-8275-4D12-A891-0BC37CE8F11F, OS:17.2, name:iPhone 15 Pro Max }
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dzwwympbnncmhxbpmvkfeqqwcchk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.o /Users/[USER]/Desktop/react-native-mobile/ios/ReactNativeMobile/AppDelegate.mm normal arm64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'ReactNativeMobile' from project 'ReactNativeMobile')
(1 failure)
]

Node.js v20.9.0
```

I have no idea what's happen, I have a problem with my computer for sure.

I can say:

- The project folder have no space.
- I removed the cache and index of Xcode.
- Look on Google and ask Chat GPT.
- I deleted the `node_modules` folder, `package-lock.json` file and clean the cache of node, then `npm install`.
- Restart my computer again (maybe...)
- I tried to not use Flipper, maybe I didn't make this good, but I got next error.
- I started a new project from scratch, same issue.
- I also tried this: [How to fix cocoapod .modulemap file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55675694/how-to-fix-cocoapod-modulemap-file-not-found/57888449#57888449)

My command: `npm run ios -- --simulator="iPhone 15 Pro Max (17.2)"`
My ReactNative version: `"react-native": "0.73.2"`
My GemFile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# You may use http://rbenv.org/ or https://rvm.io/ to install and use this version
ruby ">= 2.6.10"

gem 'cocoapods', '1.15.0'
gem 'activesupport', '>= 6.1.7.3', '< 7.1.0'
```

If I use `nom run iOS`, I got this error:

```
info A dev server is already running for this project on port 8081.
info Found Xcode workspace "ReactNativeMobile.xcworkspace"
info Found booted iPhone, iPhone 15 Pro Max
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace ReactNativeMobile.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme ReactNativeMobile -destination id=00008020-001138E81178002E")

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor 

error Failed to build iOS project. "xcodebuild" exited with error code '70'. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening 'ReactNativeMobile.xcworkspace'.
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace ReactNativeMobile.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme ReactNativeMobile -destination id=00008020-001138E81178002E

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES


2024-03-08 19:25:58.943 xcodebuild[5166:64572] Writing error result bundle to /var/folders/ff/8z0rnxqx6k9c6b_cvwb296wm0000gn/T/ResultBundle_2024-08-03_19-25-0058.xcresult
xcodebuild: error: Timed out waiting for all destinations matching the provided destination specifier to become available


    Available destinations for the "ReactNativeMobile" scheme:
        { platform:iOS, arch:arm64, id:00008020-001138E81178002E, name:iPhone, error:iPhone needs to be prepared for development Development services need to be enabled. Ensure that the device is unlocked. }
```

So, I have no more ideas...