# error using Cocoapod with Firestore to target iOS Extension

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use Firestore in my iOS Widget. When I run pod update and then clean,  build, I get the following:

```
error: unable to read module map contents from 'Target Support Files/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities.modulemap': Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “GoogleUtilities.modulemap” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/James/Documents/Development/INDX420/Pods/Target Support Files/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities.modulemap, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fb732c13f30 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

warning: no umbrella header found for target 'GoogleUtilities', module map will not be generated

Thoughts?

EDIT: I got through that after first dealing with a Facebook API issue. Anyway now it compiles my  main  target but dies instantly with this error

```
 dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GULAppDelegateSwizzler
```

Referenced from: /Users/James/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E3EF00D4-577A-43CF-85DC-95209216A72D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BC790D62-8CC5-4CF5-9330-4BF6E264BBBB/INDX01.app/INDX01
  Expected in: /Users/James/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E3EF00D4-577A-43CF-85DC-95209216A72D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BC790D62-8CC5-4CF5-9330-4BF6E264BBBB/INDX01.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities
 in /Users/James/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E3EF00D4-577A-43CF-85DC-95209216A72D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BC790D62-8CC5-4CF5-9330-4BF6E264BBBB/INDX01.app/INDX01

Now this is in the main target which works if I take out the firestore pod from the widget target. I have done countless remove all pods, install,  update, delete, clean build a dozen times on this issue

Comment: Hey @jimijon where you able to configure Firebase in the extension? I've been facing the same issue and tried many ways to make it work with no success.

Comment: @drdrdrdr unfortunately no. So i punted at the time and used a different approach to access the data

Answer (score 0):

Please try this steps:
  First step:
(this step may no longer be needed in Xcode 9.x and newer)

```
1.Open Xcode
2.Click Window (Menu Bar)
3.Click Projects
4.Remove all projects (e.g. use backspace)
5.Close Xcode
```

Second Step:

```
1.Open a terminal app
2.cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
3.rm -rf Build/* see below if you have a customized build location
4.rm -rf ModuleCache/*
5.Close a terminal app
```

Third Step:

```
1.Open Xcode
2.Product > Clean
3.Product > Run
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30752152/756976

Comment: Have you actually successfully  installed Firestore via cocoapods in an iOS Extension target?